# Getting Current date and time

Tags: android, date, datetime, calendar

I tried to access current datetime in android application as follows :

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            //long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
 Date date2 = new Date(seconds);
 Log.d(">>>>>>>Current Date : ",""+date2);
```

It gives me date and time with the year 1970 as follows :

```
>>>>>>>Current Date :﹕ Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 GMT+05:30 1970
```

but, It should be 2015 instead of 1970.
What the problem is ?

> > > I have solved above problem from solution provided. Atually, I am generating notification as the datetime value from the databse matches to the current datetime value. but, it does not generating notification.

My code is as follows :

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    doAsynchTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("Timer Task Background", "Timer task background");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(new Date());
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Date dateCurrent = new Date(time);
            Log.d(">>>>>>>Current Date : ", "" + dateCurrent);

            getListData();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
            Date dateFromDatabase;
            for (int i = 0; i < remiderList.size(); i++) {

                try {
                    System.out.print("+++" + remiderList.get(i).toString());
                    dateFromDatabase = formatter.parse(remiderList.get(i).toString());
                    Log.d(">>>>>Database date  : ", "" + dateFromDatabase);
                    if (dateCurrent.equals(dateFromDatabase)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        displayNotification();
                    }


                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchTask, 0, 1000);


}

public void displayNotification() {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MyRemiderService.this);


    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
            HomeActivity.class);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_template_icon_bg,
            "This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha)
            .setContentTitle("ContentTitle").setContentText("this for test massage")
            .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);

    notification = builder.getNotification();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   /* notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
            "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!",
            pendingNotificationIntent);*/

    mManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
}

public void getListData() {
    remiderList = dbHelper.getAllRemiders();
}
```

I have checked both the values in Logcat as follows :

```
09-15 17:50:00.629  17915-17927/? D/>>>>>>>Current Date :﹕ Tue Sep 15 17:50:00 GMT+05:30 2015

09-15 17:50:00.637  17915-17927/? D/>>>>>Database date  :﹕ Tue Sep 15 17:50:00 GMT+05:30 2015
```

Comment: Check your phone date time setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set current date in calender object.

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date());
    //Calendar.SECOND will return only seconds from the date
    //int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    long time = c.getTime();
    Date date2 = new Date(time);
    Log.d(">>>>>>>Current Date : ",""+date2);
```

You can use SimpleDateFormat class to format the dates as follow

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private String getCurrentDateAndTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat simple = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return simple.format(new Date());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid old date-time classes

You are using the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java such as java.util.Date/.Calendar. They have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

Among the many points of confusion is that a java.util.Date represents a calendar date *and* a time-of-day while a java.sql.Date pretends to represent only a date without any time-of-day although it does actually have a time-of-day just set to zeros (`00:00:00.0`).

## java.time

The old date-time classes have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

- Java 8 and later: The java.time framework is built-in.
- Java 7 & 6: Use the [backport of java.time](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- Android: Use [this wrapped version of that backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### java.sql

Eventually we should see JDBC drivers updated to deal with java.time types directly. Until then, we still need the [java.sql](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) types for getting data in/out of databases. But immediately call the new conversion methods added to the old classes to move into java.time types.

### `Instant`

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in UTC with resolution up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( x );
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

### `LocalDate`

If you are trying to compare the date-portion of that date time to today’s date, use the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. This class truly represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

### Time Zone

Note that a time zone is **crucial** to determining dates, as the date may vary around the world by time zone for any given moment. So before extracting the `LocalDate` we need to apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). If you omit the time zone your JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. Better to specify explicitly the desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ); // Or "Asia/Kolkata", "Europe/Paris", and so on.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
if( today.isEqual( zdt.toLocalDate() ) {
    …
}
```

Notice that nowhere in that code did we use Strings; all date-time objects instead.

### Formatting Strings

To generate a `String` as a textual representation of the date-time value, you can call the `toString` methods to get text formatted using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Or specify your own formatting pattern. Better yet, let java.time do the work of localizing automatically. Specify a `Locale` for a human language (English, French, etc.) to use in translating the name of day/month and such.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM );
String output = zdt.format( formatter.withLocale( Locale.US ) );  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH and so on.
```